# visual studio setup project - install for all users

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, setup-project

I have a visual studio setup project which installs my files to the program files folder and also writes some stuff into the registry and in addition some of the files are com visible (so there is more confusing stuff written to the registry).

Therefore I have to install it as an administrator - this works fine. And this administrator and every other administrator is able to start the program. But using a standard user I am not able to start the program.

All registry entries are there for the standard user - and it also has enough rights to access the file in the Program Files folder.

Could there be a problem with the ComVisibility? (Which is needed because it's actually a DLL working as a plugin for Solidworks)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to look at the code in your app and see what it does that limited users can't do. Installing it for all users does not mean that it automatically allows limited users to violate security. Just find out what it's doing when it gets the security error (which is what you believe it is).

Limited users have never been able to write to restricted areas such as the ProgramFiles folder, CommonFiles folder, HKLM etc. That's a common reason for limited user issues with apps.